# using strongly typed partial views inside another Strongly Typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, strongly-typed-view

I have NameModel and RegisterModel and SuperClass classes as below: -

**Case 1: - Using SuperClass**

```
public class SuperClass
{
   public RegisterModel Register{ get; set; }
   public NameModel NameInfo { get; set; }
}

public class NameModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

  public class RegisterModel
    {       
        public NameModel NameInfo{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; } 
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set;}
    }
```

MyNamePartial strongly typed View is as follows :-

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.NameModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName,new { @id="firstName"} )
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.MiddleName,new { @id="middleName"} )
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.LastName,new { @id="lastName"} )
}
```

My Registration View is strongly typed of Register Model as follows :-

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.SuperClass
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
   <div id="form">
       @Html.Partial("NameModel",Model.NameInfo)       
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Register.UserName,new { @id="userName"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Register.Password,new { @id="password"})
    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="btnRegister" />
  </div>
}
```

Above approach gives object reference error.

**Case 2: -  Using HTML.Action and no SuperClass** 
Tried using @Html.Action("MyNamePartialView")instead of  @Html.Partial("NameModel",Model.NameInfo),Then I use Controller Action method as below

My Registration View is strongly typed of Register Model as follows :-

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
   <div id="form">
      @Html.Action("MyNamePartialView")

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName,new { @id="userName"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Password,new { @id="password"})
    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="btnRegister" />
   </div>
}
```

Register Controller :-

```
  public ActionResult MyNamePartialView()
  {            
      return PartialView("MyNamePartial", new NameModel());
  }      

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterrModel model)
{
    @ViewBag.sideMenuHeader = "Create an Account";

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          //Perform Something
           return View();
    }
         return View();
}
```

The above case doesnt bind the values entered on form. it sets null for NameModel.

I don't want to use EditorFor as i have to supply html and custom attributes to helpers.The binding for the partial view fails.it gives me object reference error in Registration view. How can i use such strongly typed Partial views with such a such Model class hierarchy as explained above ?

Comment: 2 ways. 1) create a `superclass` containing both models. 2) use a partial with child action method. The child action will instantiate and pass the View Model to your partial.

Comment: Thanks @DaveA. Can you please explain the options ? I didn't get it exactly.

Comment: you can create a class that contains both NameModel and RegisterModel and pass that to your view. Then you could pass @Model.NameModel to your partial while using the RegisterModel to bind your controls.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a child action for your partial. A Partial with child action is called with syntax Html.Action("Action Name")... the child action can instantiate a model and pass it to the partial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use a child action

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.Register.SuperModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
   <div id="form">
       @Html.Action("MyNamePartialView")
   </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Register.UserName,new { @id="userName"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Register.Password,new { @id="password"})
    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="btnRegister" />
}
```

make your action post accept 2 classes

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel RegisterInfo, NameModel NameInfo)
```

Comment: Thanks @DaveA , In @Html.Partial("NameModel",@Model.Name.NameInfo)  "Name" does not have NameInfo.I changed it to @Html.Partial("NameModel",@Model.Name) but it breaks with object reference error at same place.

Comment: @user2232861, Please see my edit. I meant to name the parent class SuperModel. More importantly, please add your action method in which you instantiate your classes and pass them to your View.

Comment: I did tried @Html.Action("MyNamePartialView") and then my action method is 
 public ActionResult MyNamePartialView()
        {            
            return PartialView("MyNamePartial", new NameModel());
        }
it loads fine but when i submit form after filling in , it only binds Register class with form values but the Name class is null.

Comment: @user2232861, I'm confused. I see that now you're using a child action in which case you don't need a super model. But I don't see you actually **instantiate** your model class. Please add the code to your question, not to a comment.

Comment: I have edited the code above to add both cases. Please check if i have appropriate class structure and have coded as per you suggested.

Comment: @user2232861, I think I see. Are you using the same partial when you use a child `Action`?

Comment: Inside the main RegistrationView which is of strongly types Registerodel I call @Html.Action("MyNamePartialView"),'MyNamePartialView' is strongly typed view of class 'NameModel'.

Comment: @user2232861, your post method only takes RegisterModel? no other values?

Comment: Yes , it takes only RegisterModel. How can I pass more than one model or other values.

Comment: @user2232861, I edited my answer. Try taking both models as params. LMK if they bind.

Comment: Awesome !!! it worked. Such a simple thing and it looks so long to figure out. Credit goes to Dave !!!